# Cookie does not work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have two pages, test1.aspx and test2.aspx

test1.aspx has this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test", "test");
  cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
  Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```

test2.aspx has this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Write(Response.Cookies["test"].Value);
}
```

The value of the cookie is null, no matter how many times I tried. I tried to open page1 and then page 2, expecting a cookie to work, but it is not working, I don't know why.

Comment: Why did you edit your question so the code example for shows `Respond.Cookies` instead of `Response.Cookies`?

Comment: I have tried to edit from Response to Request but it still not work and find out that it works later so i change it back to be reponse to make this a valid question but i mistyped it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to read off the `Request` instead of the response.

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18) suggestions

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies["test"].Value);
}
```

In a web application, the *request* comes from the client (browser) and the *response* is sent from the server. When validating cookies or cookie data from the browser you should use the `Request.Cookies` collection. When you are constructing cookies to be sent to the browser you need to add them to the `Response.Cookies` collection.

**Additional thoughts on the use of SetCookie**

Interestingly for [HttpResponse.SetCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie) as used on your first page; MSDN says this method is not intended for use in your code.

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Even the example code found on this page uses the `Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie)` approach and does not call `SetCookie`

Answer (score 2):

You need is :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Response.Write(Request.Cookies["test"].Value);
}
```

There is a sample here:
 [Reading and Writing Cookies in ASP.NET and C#](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/cookies-csharp.aspx)

Regards

Comment: You need to add a check for null or you will get a NullReferenceException if the cookie does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Save cookie with (response) and read cookie by (request)

```
//write
response.cookies("abc") = 123;

//read
if ((request.cookies("abc") != null)) {
string abc = request.cookies("abc");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies

Comment: Yeah. I realized that I should have mentioned that after posting that link.

Comment: To elaborate, you use Request.Cookies even if you are still on the server and have added your cookie to the Response.  Is there a difference in usage between Cookies.Add and SetCookie?

Comment: Well MSDN suggests SetCookie is not intended for direct use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.httpresponse.setcookie

Answer (score 0):

On page test2.aspx

You should try this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpCookie = Request.Cookies["test"];
        if (httpCookie != null) 
        {
            Response.Write(httpCookie.Value);
        }
    }
```